# How can I open listen ports on an Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: webserver, web-development, amazon-ec2, ports

I'm using Amazon EC2 micro instance with Ubuntu 11.04 on it (official AMI by Canonical). I have created a new security group for this instance:

```
Inbound:

22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0
443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0
3306 (MYSQL)    0.0.0.0/0
8080 (HTTP*)    0.0.0.0/0
27017   0.0.0.0/0
27018   0.0.0.0/0
27019   0.0.0.0/0
28017   0.0.0.0/0
```

But when I start the web server on 8080 and try to open `http://ec2-ip-address:8080/` in my browser it says

> Server Not Found

… with the standard Google Chrome page.

```
netstat -anltp | grep "LISTEN"
```

says that my only port listened at is 22.

How can I open the listed ports so I can start my web projects?

**EDIT:** The solution has been found. All you need is to start server at 0.0.0.0 IP address, not 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

Comment: This solved my problem as well using Google App Eninge on EC2. Have to start it using `dev_appserver.py --host=0.0.0.0` to be able to connect from outside.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few possibilities here. First possibility is that you haven't set that port up as a listener in Apache, you can do this by adding a line like

```
Listen 8080
```

Into you Apache configuration file.

The second possibility is that UFW is running (ubuntu Firewall), you can disable this by running

```
sudo ufw disable
```

or add ports to it via

```
sudo ufw allow 8080
```

The last possibility is IPTables is blocking it, you would need to look at

```
sudo iptables -L
```

to get a list of rules and change them from there.

Comment: I'm not using Apache, disabled ufw and clear all iptables

Comment: OK, Sorry, I assumed you were using apache, it seems like whatever is supposed to be listening on port 8080/80/443 etc is not configured/started. What webserver are you using, perhaps I can help with that.

Comment: I'm using standard webserver which comes with CherryPy Python web framework.

Comment: Yes, so that is not starting up, or running. You will have to look into how to start the webserver that comes with CherryPy, as I am not familiar with that.

Comment: After looking around 1000 blogs and bla bla I found this as working solution for me. Thanks bro from soul of my heart